# How to display image on a web-page from a url

Tags: java, image, servlets, web-applications

Following is the snippet from a servlet that attempts to fetch image from the `URL`. I have fetched the bytes. Now how do I display the image on the webpage ?

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://abc/zhdhaG1z_bigger.jpeg");
        InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while(-1 != (n = stream.read(buf)) ) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        byte res[] = bos.toByteArray();

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Rewrite your code like this...see if this helps

```
public void doGet(HttpRequest request,HttpResponse response)throws ServletException{

response.setContentType("image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8");    
response.addHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=Default.jpeg");

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://abc/zhdhaG1z_bigger.jpeg");
        InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new OutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while(-1 != (n = stream.read(buf)) ) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, n);
        }

    } 
     catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTarce();
     }

    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer

Comment: content-type="text/jpeg" will tell that response is an image  not a plain text.I added content disposition by thinking that you want to display in a different browser window. If you want it to view it in your own web page Do Like this......                                           Firstly Include <a href="servlet1">click for photo</a> in your web Page and remove Content.addhadder statement from servlet.                                                          Here servlet1 is the pattern for calling servlet it will be included in your web.xml. It will serve your purpose.

Comment: Sorry, Content-type=image/jpeg not text/jpeg.....and one more thing if it's not working take ServletOutStream object and write the response bytes on this stream...